# Getting what I thought was a good result but is not sufficient

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am working on a word cloud problem. I thought that my result covered the requirements as it produces a word cloud without the uninteresting words or punctuation, but apparently not. I cannot figure out what I am missing.

The script needs to process the text, remove punctuation, ignore cases and words that do not contain all alphabets, count the frequencies, and ignore uninteresting or irrelevant words. A dictionary is the output of the `calculate_frequencies` function. The wordcloud module will then generate the image from your dictionary.

My code:

```
def calculate_frequencies(file_contents):
    # Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
    "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
    "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
    "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
    "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just", \
    "in", "for", "so" ,"on", "says", "not", "into", "because", "could", "out", "up", "back", "about"]
    
    # LEARNER CODE START HERE
      
    frequencies = {}
    words = file_contents.split()
    final_words = []
    
    
    
    for item in words:
        item = item.lower()
        
        if item in punctuations:
            words = words.replace(item, "")
                  
        if item not in uninteresting_words and item.isalpha()==True:
            final_words.append(item)
            
    for final in final_words:
        
        if final not in frequencies:
                frequencies[final]=0
        else:
                frequencies[final]+=1
                
    #wordcloud
    cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
    cloud.generate_from_frequencies(frequencies)
    return cloud.to_array()
```

Comment: `words.replace` while you are iterating over `words` is probably a bad idea

Comment: You haven't said why it is deemed insufficient. Split probably only splits on whitespace, and punctuation follows words. Um, and you might want to do something pythonesque with a filter over a stream or something.

Comment: Please choose a better title of the question - it is not revealing any information about the problem. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) short intro on how to ask questions on SO.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

##### So here is some different approach!

`punctuations` and `uninteresting_words` are given separately off course for to students understand easily. Since, both of them are same `str` type simply concatenating them saves us work. Doing such reduces iteration to just one time only and script gets lot simpler and clean.

```
def calculate_frequencies(file_contents):
    # Here is a list of punctuations and uninteresting words you can use to process your text
    punctuations = '''!()-[]{};:'"\,<>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    uninteresting_words = ["the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
    "we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
    "their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
    "have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
    "all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just"]
    
    # LEARNER CODE START HERE
    
    frequencies = {}
    junk = punctuations + " ".join(uninteresting_words)
    lower_txt = file_contents.lower()
    
    for word in lower_txt.split(" ") :
        if word not in junk and word.isalpha() :
            frequencies[word] = lower_txt.count(word)
            
    
    #wordcloud
    cloud = wordcloud.WordCloud()
    cloud.generate_from_frequencies(frequencies)
    return cloud.to_array()
```

Question asked frequencies of word in given text file. `count()` comes in very handy for this.

Answer (score -1):

As written, I don't think your code runs. `words` is a list, and  `.replace` is not a valid `list` method.

---

To simply get the counts, see this code

For punctuation refer - [Best way to strip punctuation from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string)

For counting, use a `Counter`

```
import string
from collections import Counter

uninteresting_words = {"the", "a", "to", "if", "is", "it", "of", "and", "or", "an", "as", "i", "me", "my", \
"we", "our", "ours", "you", "your", "yours", "he", "she", "him", "his", "her", "hers", "its", "they", "them", \
"their", "what", "which", "who", "whom", "this", "that", "am", "are", "was", "were", "be", "been", "being", \
"have", "has", "had", "do", "does", "did", "but", "at", "by", "with", "from", "here", "when", "where", "how", \
"all", "any", "both", "each", "few", "more", "some", "such", "no", "nor", "too", "very", "can", "will", "just", \
"in", "for", "so" ,"on", "says", "not", "into", "because", "could", "out", "up", "back", "about"}

def calculate_frequencies(s):
  global uninteresting_words
  words = (x.lower().strip().translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)) for x in s.strip().split())

  c = Counter(words)
  for x in uninteresting_words:
    if x in c:
      del c[x]
  return c

print(calculate_frequencies('this is a string! A very fancy string?'))
# Counter({'string': 2, 'fancy': 1})
```

---

For a WordCloud, you shouldn't need to count anything, as it would do it for you. Notice there is a parameter for `stopwords` and a `process_text` function that uses a regex pattern that ignores punctuation by default - https://amueller.github.io/word_cloud/generated/wordcloud.WordCloud.html